# Alignment With Different Resolution

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I facing some issues for the table alignment over an image which I can't figure out which part is no correct. My table alignment is totally out of expectation when view by using different resolution device(laptop,TV) below is my code.

```
#image_overlay_panel {
  width:100% !important;
  float: left;
}

#image_overlay_panel .image{
background: transparent 50% 50% no-repeat url('/iameg/Acer_schematics.png');        
position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 808px;
 background-size: 100%;
}

#effTablehtml{
 position:absolute;
 top: 28%;
 left: 80%;
 color: black;
}
```

I had try to removed height: 808px; and my whole image become very small as attachment below. Mind to share what mistake did I make. Thank you very much.
[image]

Comment: If it's ok if some part of the image is not shown, then you can use background-size:cover instead of 100%, and remove width and height attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to responsive to all screen, try to fix this rules in your code

```css
#image_overlay_panel .image{
background: transparent 50% 50% no-repeat url('/iameg/Acer_schematics.png');       
position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 //width: 100%; <-- comment this line
 //height: 808px; <-- comment this line
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: hi jirayu, thank you very much for ur effort. unfortunately it can't work. The image and table squeeze to a small panel.

Comment: the image as attachment. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can use media screen css , as per your requirement

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
    }
}
```